# Using NLTK With Badly Formatted Input

Tags: nltk

I would like to use NLTK's PCFGs to parse badly formatted descriptions; for instance apartment listings from old style classified ads.  The listings might look something like this:

```
2BR 2BTH 1400sqft $2000/mo washer dryer, close to downtown
```

Since the listings are manually entered spaces can be out of place, and the sequence can change:

```
$2000 2BR2BTH1400ft washer, dryer, new york city
```

or worse

```
$2000 2BR2BTH1400ft washdry newyorkcity
$2000 2BR2BTH1400ft washdry closetodowntown
```

I wanted to use a PCFG or a CFG, however it seems that NLTK wants the input string to be tokenized prior to parsing.  What does NLTK want me to do with tokens that don't trivially fall out of the tokenizer as shown above?

Thanks!

Comment: This sort of telegraphic advertising doesn't contain a lot of "natural language" or "syntax". Probably you could write a specialized "translator" for this particular genre and get something useful done much quicker than by trying to adapt NLTK to do something it wasn't designed to do.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks, I had a feeling that might be the case.  One thought, NLTK appears to have a way of dealing with ambiguity by using ngrams generated from a corpus to produce the most probable tag for a token.  If that were extensible I could aggressively tokenize the string and reform concepts using the grammar. I.e. there would need to be a way to provide multiple tags per token.

Comment: You can train it on anything you like but the training input needs to be tokens.  It is quite normal for words in natural language to have multiple readings depending on context so just mark up with the tag which is correct in that context.  But again, decrypting the input and then handling it by regular means would seem like a more fruitful approach.

Comment: Agree with tripleee that there isn't a whole lot of natural language or syntax going on here. However, as an alternative to decrypting and handling it by regular means, you could think of making an inventory of all the words/phrases (n-grams) that appear in your data, and taking it from there to do something that may even bypass your regular NLP. As I suspect typically the vocabulary will be quite limited for these types of texts. And of course, everything depends on what you want to do with this once you have your input parsed...

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.  I want to derive a tool that requires minimal customization to tackle this type of problem. The tool's goal is to a return a data structure that describes the information available in the description string.  I had hoped to use the PCFG to resolve the most likely/or strongest match of the possible interpretations.

Comment: The NLTK expects you to do your own tokenization if splitting on whitespace is not enough. It would be trivial to split strings like `2BR2BTH1400ft` into "2 BR 2 BTH 1400 ft", for example. That said, hand-crafted rules like small (P)CFGs are completely inadequate for text in the wild. If you really need a parser, look for machine learning approaches.